# Catalina-Opts with string parameter is not working

Tags: linux, tomcat8, catalina

On my linux machine I want to configure tomcat 8 with the following

```
catalina_opts:
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Dsina.elasticsearch.cluster.nodes=sina-1:9300 -Dsina.elasticsearch.cluster.name=sinasuite-dev -Dsina.rabbitmq.host=sina-1 -Dsina.rabbitmq.port=5672 -Dsina.rabbitmq.user=guest -Dsina.rabbitmq.password=guest -Dsina.images.directory=/home/dev/tmp -Dsina.forms.directory=/home/dev/tmp -Dsina.scheduler.rate=30000 -Dsina.alfresco.url=http://ares:8181/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser -Dsina.alfresco.site=/Sitios/sina-suite-dev/documentLibrary -Dsina.alfresco.repository=-default- -Dsina.alfresco.user=admin -Dsina.alfresco.password=admin -Dsina.cas.server.host=sina-1.alfatecsistemas.es -Dsina.cas.server.port=9444 -Dsina.cas.service.host=sina-1 -Dsina.cas.service.port=9443 -Dsina.cas.service.appname=sina-suite -Dsina.forms.pdf.files.directory=/home/dev/tmp -Dsina.fileupload.size=250000000 -Dsina.farhos.url.login=https://www.detots.com/farhos/token?usuario=%s&clave=%s -Dsina.farhos.url.component=https://www.detots.com/farhos/5/?vista=%s&paciente=%s&episodio=%s&token=%s -Dsina.nurse.profile.id=1 -Dsina.farhos.url.logout=https://www.detots.com/farhos/token?%s"
```

But on trying to start tomcat I'm getting the error:

```
/home/dev/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: -Dsina.farhos.url.logout=https://www.detots.com/farhos/token?%s: No such file or directory
/home/dev/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: -Dsina.nurse.profile.id=1: command not found
/home/dev/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: -Dsina.farhos.url.component=https://www.detots.com/farhos/5/?vista=%s: No such file or directory
/home/dev/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: line 434: -Dsina.nurse.profile.id=1: command not found
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to surround URLs with single quotes.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS \
 -Dsina.elasticsearch.cluster.nodes=sina-1:9300 \
 -Dsina.elasticsearch.cluster.name=sinasuite-dev \
 -Dsina.rabbitmq.host=sina-1 \
 -Dsina.rabbitmq.port=5672 \
 -Dsina.rabbitmq.user=guest \
 -Dsina.rabbitmq.password=guest \
 -Dsina.images.directory=/home/dev/tmp \
 -Dsina.forms.directory=/home/dev/tmp \
 -Dsina.scheduler.rate=30000 \
 -Dsina.alfresco.url='http://ares:8181/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser' \
 -Dsina.alfresco.site=/Sitios/sina-suite-dev/documentLibrary \
 -Dsina.alfresco.repository=-default- \
 -Dsina.alfresco.user=admin \
 -Dsina.alfresco.password=admin \
 -Dsina.cas.server.host=sina-1.alfatecsistemas.es \
 -Dsina.cas.server.port=9444 \
 -Dsina.cas.service.host=sina-1 \
 -Dsina.cas.service.port=9443 \
 -Dsina.cas.service.appname=sina-suite \
 -Dsina.forms.pdf.files.directory=/home/dev/tmp \
 -Dsina.fileupload.size=250000000 \
 -Dsina.farhos.url.login='https://www.detots.com/farhos/token?usuario=%s&clave=%s' \
 -Dsina.farhos.url.component='https://www.detots.com/farhos/5/?vista=%s&paciente=%s&episodio=%s&token=%s' \
 -Dsina.nurse.profile.id=1 \
 -Dsina.farhos.url.logout='https://www.detots.com/farhos/token?%s'"
```

FYI, It is recommended to add `CATALINA_OPTS` to `bin/setenv.sh`.